# Moto G device storage randomly gets full

Tags: internal-storage, motorola-moto-g

I never had this issue prior to installing CM 12.1 on my Moto G 8GB. But now, every often (like after 5 days of clean install from reset) the storage gets full. After that the device becomes useless, can't install app, can't remove apps, can't view storage options, and etc.

When connecting the phone to a computer I see this :

[image]

and folders inside it :

[image]

majority of the folders such as Pictures, DCIM, and Downloads are empty.

```
android folder is : 1.05MB
com.facebook.orca is: 1KB
tbslog is:75KB
tencent is: 43MB
```

It says 3.85 GB is used, the phone is 8GB and only shows 5.52 GB. I assume Android OS is installed on the missing storage, since I dont have anything why this device gets full so fast?

I only have 5 or 6 other apps (like Gmail, Maps, Chrome and Facebook).

I keep resetting the phone to get the storage back but not sure why is this keep happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you check with *Settings › Storage* (and integrate a screenshot with your question)? Also see our [internal-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info) for some hints.

Comment: @izzy the settings > storage is unresponsive. I have checked and it shows `calculating` but it never finishes

Comment: Analysing the storage with [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=de) might give us a better idea :) you can try it out **if** you're able to install it - but the app is very small

Comment: @benjaminS exactly -- one of the hints linked from above mentioned tag-wiki AFAIR :)